# testFlight external user test need demo account and content

Tags: ios, testflight

i am using testflight for client test our application. I got these information:

> From Apple
>   2. 1 Performance: App Completeness Guideline 2.1 - Information Needed
>
> We have started the review of your beta app, but we are not able to
>   continue because we need a demo account to fully assess your app
>   features.
>
> Next Steps
>
> To help us proceed with the review of your app, please provide a user
>   name and password in the Beta App Review Information section for your
>   app in iTunes Connect. Please be sure to include content in your app
>   that demonstrates the features and functionality available in your
>   app.
>
> Since your iTunes Connect status shows as Rejected, we require a new
>   binary to correct this issue. Once the requested information is
>   available, we can continue your review.
>
> To provide demo account information:
>
> - Log in to iTunes Connect
> - Click on "My Apps"
> - Select your app
> - Select “Test Information”
> - Scroll down to “Beta App Review Information”
> - Provide information in “Demo Account” and/or “Review Notes” as appropriate
> - Click “Save”
> - Scroll up to “Builds” section and submit a new binary for review

I provided the demo user account and password. But it's still with this error like:
[image]

So i am just wondering

```
Please be sure to include content in your app that demonstrates the features and functionality available in your app.
```

what's the content means here? Or i missed something important. How long does this testFlight review cost if it fails first? 
Thanks for the help!

**EDIT** I am wondering if the **content in your app** means the **Review Notes** in the below image.
[image]

Comment: did you provided new binary?

Comment: @Indrajeet Yes.

Comment: I am  also facing same issue i have added username and password and save it but after that i am not able to find this option could anyone please help in that the option is :  Scroll up to “Builds” section and submit a new binary for review

Comment: or is i need to give build again with new version???

Comment: @Asmita Should be, not sure why you can't find it. Normally it just likes you create a new version. And fill in all the required parts. There are all on the same page including "Builds" If you still can't find it, try to post some screenshot.

Comment: @WilliamHu i have added screenshot please check

Comment: @Asmita Please don't edit the question, your issue is off the topic of the original question. Just share a link let me see. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After filled **Review Notes** the error was gone. And the review the finished the second day.

Answer (score 1):

**You just need to go to**

> AppStore -> My Apps ->  Select Your App ->  select
>   TestFlight Tab -> Test Information Tab

**Then fill testing account info and wait for reviewer **
[image]

Comment: Do we need to add another release after we set the demo account details ?

Comment: if it's status was binary rejected you will have to upload a new build.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the description, it seems like your application needs some specific account to login to use application features. So, Apple people do not have access to your application until you provide them the testing account to log into the application.

You do not need to re-submit the application binary. You just need to provide account information to access your application. That is what they mean to say in description.

Please let me know if this information helps you